# JQuery: Click to show hide individual paragraphs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a site that will have a summary paragraph with the option to extend for more info on click. I have done this with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#here").hide();
$("#show").click(function() {
    $("#here").show();
    $("#icond").hide();
});

$("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#here").hide();
    $("#icond").show();
});
```

My issue is that I want to be able to do this a number of times throughout the page with different div/p elements.

When I attempted to do this with classes it would open/close all at the same time. The only solution I know of is to retype the function for each id.

Is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/58roy7hg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the `this` keyword and then use [tree traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/%20tree%20traversal) to target particular elements you want to show and hide as the answer above suggests. Some additional tips I would give you are:

1. Avoid using `document.ready` multiple times.
2. I would suggest using `.on` instead of `.click`, as it is more versatile, allowing you to drill-down to dynamically added elements.
3. Avoid using `id` too much; this is to be used for elements that are not repeated throughout the page (e.g. navigation bar). Most of your `id` can be replaced with `class`.

Try out this sample: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58roy7hg/4/)

I just quickly made a sample (with my own markup) to show you, so you can re-purpose it as you wish, but I would definitely recommend checking out the documentation to gain a feel.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this` variable in order to work with a particular event source element. Identify all other elements relatively. I assume you will have the same structure for each block. Note I've added a `container` class to each block `<p/>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".here").hide();
    $(".show").click(function() {
        var container = $(this).closest(".container");
        container.find(".here").show();
        container.find(".icond").hide();
    });

    $(".hide").click(function() {
        var container = $(this).closest(".container");
        container.find(".here").hide();
        container.find(".icond").show();
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    width:70%;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="container">This is my main text, this will display as a normal paragraph. If someone needs more information     <span class="show"> they would click here <i class="icond" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">v</i></span>
    <span class="here"><br><span class="hide"><strong>Wow!</strong> Clicking brings up more information. When they've had enough, they'll click again and it'll go away.
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true">^</i>
    </span></span>
</p>

<p class="container">This is great and works exactly as I want it too but there is a problem <span class="show"> ...
    <i class="icond" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">v</i></span>
    <span class="here"><br><span class="hide">I need this to work over and over for different paragraphs individually.
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true">^</i>
    </span></span>
</p>
<p class="container">Targeting classes resulted in all paragraphs colapsing at the same time<span class="show"> and
    <i class="icond" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">v</i></span>
    <span class="here"><br><span class="hide">Rewriting the function for a new set of ids each time cant be the best way to do this...
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true">^</i>
    </span></span>
</p>
<p class="container"><span class="show"> Please help!
    <i class="icond" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">v</i></span>
    <span class="here"><br><span class="hide">I'm just starting out with JS, please be kind..
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true">^</i>
    </span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks all. I've still got a long way to go with JS. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution might depend on how you are creating the page (php, straight HTML?).  Some vanilla javascript for you.  I use something like this when I'm creating a page through php but will work just the same for html.

```
<div onclick="myDropdown('extraSummary1');">my visible text -click for
more</div>
<div id="extraSummary1" style="display: none;">hidden extra text</div>
<script>
function myDropdown(theDiv){
if (document.getElementById(theDiv).style.display=='none')
    { document.getElementById(theDiv).style.display='block'; }
else { document.getElementById(theDiv).style.display='none'; }
</script>
```